# Symbol(s) not found for architecture ARM64 clang--error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, ld

I get this error when I try to get build. I have updated my pods, but not resolved.

```
   "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::object::object(_xmlXPathObject*) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:
      lxml::xml::xml(void const*, unsigned long, char const*, char const*, int) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "___xmlLastError", referenced from:
      lxml::xml::xml(void const*, unsigned long, char const*, char const*, int) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathCastToBoolean", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::object::boolean() in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathCastToString", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::object::string() in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:
      lxml::xml::xml(void const*, unsigned long, char const*, char const*, int) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:
      +[FNFMediaPresentationDescription presentationDescriptionWithContentsOfXml:mpdUrl:error:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathCompile", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::expression::expression(char const*) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathCastToNumber", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::object::integer() in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::xpath(lxml::xml const&, std::__1::function<void (_xmlXPathContext*)>) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathCompiledEval", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::evaluate(lxml::xpath::expression const&) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:
      lxml::xpath::object::string() in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
  "_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:
      +[FNFMediaPresentationDescription presentationDescriptionWithContentsOfXml:mpdUrl:error:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFMediaPresentationDescription.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, it is very difficult for us to help you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. If you are asking us to debug you code, please include the code. This is called a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); ensure you have sample inputs, outputs, and, if any, errors included. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems like you're missing:  `libxml2`.

Go to Xcode -> Target-> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries, click the plus sign and add `libxml2`.